# Asp.net allow Access page2.cshtml only after access to page1.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to block the option to access the page2.cshtml, and allow it only after visiting in page1.cshtml. I think that there is some code to add to the controller of page2, but i didn't found how to make it. Any help?

Comment: Does page1.cshtml redirect or has a button to go to page2?

Comment: yes there is button in page1 to page2. and i want to block the option to access page2 without it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `TempData`. Set a value in your first page, and check it in your second.

```
public ActionResult FirstPage()
{
  TempData["Visited"] = true;
}

public ActionResult SecondPage()
{
  if(TempData["Visited"] != null)
    {
       //Do your logic. Clear the temp data if needed.
       return View("SecondPage");
    }
   return View("FirstPage");
}
```